# DNS Issue or Something else?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I'm experiencing something weird when trying to point an IP address to a wordpress website for a client. For some reason, I'm getting the parking page below when I access the website from my desktop computer instead of seeing the website.

[image]

However, on my iPad (which uses Wifi from the same ISP), I can see the website fine. I can also see the website fine on my mobile phone.

[See website here](http://eurekacamper.com)

My first guess was that my ISP (Charter Spectrum) is still caching the DNS setting, but if I'm viewing it through Wifi on the same ISP, this isn't the case.

Basically this is what I have done and not sure if I missed something. I have changed the A records where the domain is located (Network Solutions) for www, @ and All to point to the IP address of the Bluehost account. I have installed an SSL on Bluehost for the domain and added htaccess redirects as follows.

htaccess file...

```
# Use PHP5.6 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what could be causing the parking page to show up on my desktop (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE all the showing it) but not my iPAD or mobile phone?

Comment: Oh an it's been almost a week since I changed IP address for the A records.

Comment: do they both resolve to the same (correct) IP address?

Comment: Hmm... with www it resolves to the correct IP address when I run a tracert in the command prompt. Without www resolves to a different one.

Comment: And with www I get an 404 error on the desktop

Comment: Hmm i think it may be something your end... If I browse to your domain with or without the www I get a page about camper (vans) Both dns's give the same results `www.eurekacamper.com is an alias for eurekacamper.com.
eurekacamper.com has address 50.87.249.176` and `eurekacamper.com has address 50.87.249.176` so it looks like its working externally.

Comment: Until I can figure it out, I have removed the redirects above... I can now see the website using the www.eurekacamper.com but without www, I still see the parking page above. I've tried flusing my DNS on my computer with no luck.

Comment: That page looks a bit like adware to me... it would be good if you can get a few other people to test, or you can test from another known good computer. Both versions still working for me